# Does a periodic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ have fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fixed-point-theorems, periodic-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function. We assume that $f$ is periodic: for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and every $a \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ we find $f(x) = f(x + a)$. Is it true that $f$ must have fixed point?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Every $x$ and every $a$?

Comment: We assume that $f(x + a) = f(x)$ holds for every x and every a, as in the statement.

I haven't tried much; the case $n = 1$ is simple and the map always has a fixed point. I'm unsure about the answer for $n \ge 2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is periodic and continuous, $f$ is bounded: say $|f(x)|\le B$ for all $x$.  So $f$ is a continuous function from the closed ball of radius $B$ about $0$ into itself.  Now use the Brouwer fixed-point theorem.